# Python function: Avoid using if clauses for parameter check

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, pymongo

this is my function:

```
def save_to_mongo(self, df, collection, additional_variable):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        result = row.to_dict()
        collection.update_one(
            {"_id": str(row['date']) + "_" + str(row['sector']) + "_" + str(row['caseid']) + str(row[additional_variable])},
            {
                '$set': result
            },
            upsert=True)
```

I have many similar functions where parameters like the `additonal_variable` can be `None`.

I would really like to avoid to bloat up the codebase with a style like this:

```
if additional_varibale is None:
    collection.update_one(
        {"_id": str(row['date']) + "_" + str(row['sector']) + "_" + str(row['caseid'])},
        {
            '$set': result
        },
        upsert=True)
else:
    collection.update_one(
        {"_id": str(row['date']) + "_" + str(row['sector']) + "_" + str(row['caseid']) + str(row[additional_variable])},
        {
            '$set': result
        },
        upsert=True)
```

I think this code is ugly and hard to maintain. Are there any better ways or best practices to avoid using these long `if` and `else` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the `if else` block to -

```
additional_varibale = '' if additional_varibale is None else str(row[additional_variable])
    
collection.update_one(
    {"_id": str(row['date']) + "_" + str(row['sector']) + "_" + str(row['caseid']) + additional_varibale},
    {
        '$set': result
    },
    upsert=True)
```

Comment: thank you, did not know these kind of ternary operators exist in python :)

Comment: Also, `'' if not additional_variable else str(row[additional_variable])`